# Regex to match motor cycle names and extract all letters and numbers separately

Tags: javascript, regex

```
(\w{1,4})(?:\s{0,1})(\d{1,4})(?:\s{0,1})(\w{1,4})\s
```

Apologies if this is really ugly regex but I am not fluent in it at all.

I need a regex function to extract all possible combinations from motor cycle names for instance:

From a Honda CBR500R I would need to get CBR, 500 and R. I am not sure if I regex could give me CBR500 and 500R as that would be really sweet!

Some type of bike names:

```
Honda CBR500R
CBR 500 R
CBR 500R
CBR500 R
GS1000 S
XYZT 1000P
500ztx
KLR250 Honda
FZR 600 Suzuki
SV650
Text here XXXX 9999 XXXX 9999 XXXXX more text here
```

Is there a way to improve my regex? making it simpler and smarter?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help because you didn't have SV650 in your list.

Comment: Looks like you could just split on `\d+` and `\s` ?

Comment: Try [`([A-Z]{2,})?[\s-]*(\d+)([a-z]+)?[\s-]*([A-Z]*\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/cL5mS4/1).

Comment: @adeneo not really as people not always include the space.

Comment: you only need the space for when there is a space, other wise it basically splits on groups of digits.

Comment: @user3434069: What is the expected result?  if taking the "type of bike names" as an example (e.g, GBR 500 R, 500ztx, all lower-case strings, etc)

Comment: @ccf I would need to get all the independent parts example 'CBR', 500, 'R'

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your regex looks like working better than mine :) Thanks ! I'll keep on trying to improve upon it\

Comment: Should I post so that you could accept?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I noticed the regex matches empty spaces (in the middle) also.

Comment: @ccf: They are matched, but not captured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
([A-Z]{2,})?[\s-]*(\d+)([a-z]+)?[\s-]*([A-Z]*\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cL5mS4/1)

The regex matches:

- `([A-Z]{2,})?` - Group 1: one or zero sequence of 2 or more capital ASCII letters
- `[\s-]*` - zero or more `-` or whitespace symbols
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `([a-z]+)?` - Group 3: one or zero sequence of one or more ASCII lowercase letters
- `[\s-]*` - zero or more `-` or whitespace symbols
- `([A-Z]*\b)` - Group 4: zero or more ASCII uppercase letters followed by a word boundary.

Here is a [sample extraction code in Python](https://ideone.com/p6JguP):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'([A-Z]{2,})?[\s-]*(\d+)([a-z]+)?[\s-]*([A-Z]*\b)')
test_str = "Honda CBR500R\nCBR 500 R\nCBR 500R\nCBR500 R\nGS1000 S\nXYZT 1000P\n500ztx\nKLR250 Honda\nFZR 600 Suzuki\nText here XXXX 9999 XXXX 9999 XXXXX more text here"
for s in p.findall(test_str):
    print("New Entry:")
    for r in s:
        if r:
            print(r)
```

Output:

```
New Entry:
CBR
500
R
New Entry:
CBR
500
R
New Entry:
CBR
500
R
New Entry:
CBR
500
R
New Entry:
GS
1000
S
New Entry:
XYZT
1000
P
New Entry:
500
ztx
New Entry:
KLR
250
New Entry:
FZR
600
New Entry:
XXXX
9999
XXXX
New Entry:
9999
XXXXX
```

Comment: Please check my answer with the code update. Hope it is of help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor. This has helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

I come up with the following pattern. No sure if it is what you expected (duplicates are not removed):

```
import re

txt = """
Honda CBR500R
CBR 500 R
CBR 500R
CBR500 R
GS1000 S
XYZT 1000P
500ztx
KLR250 Honda
FZR 600 Suzuki
SV650
Text here XXXX 9999 XXXX 9999 XXXXX more text here
"""

pattern = r'[A-Z]+\d+|\d+[A-Z]|[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|\d+[a-z]+|\d+'
print re.findall(pattern, txt)
```

Output is:

```
['CBR500', 'R', 'CBR', '500', 'R', 'CBR', '500R', 'CBR500', 'R', 'GS1000', 'S', 'XYZT', '1000P', '500ztx', 'KLR250', 'FZR', '600', 'SV650', 'XXXX', '9999', 'XXXX', '9999', 'XXXXX']
```

If you want to capture '500R' from 'CBR500R' also:

```
p1 = r'[A-Z]+\d+|(?<!\d)[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|\d+[a-z]+|\d+(?![0-9A-Z])'
p2 = r'\d+[A-Z]'
print re.findall(p1, txt) + re.findall(p2, txt)
```

Output is:

```
['CBR500', 'CBR', '500', 'R', 'CBR', 'CBR500', 'R', 'GS1000', 'S', 'XYZT', '500ztx', 'KLR250', 'FZR', '600', 'SV650', 'XXXX', '9999', 'XXXX', '9999', 'XXXXX', '500R', '500R', '1000P']
```